# Conversão de dados Long para Varchar

Tags: sql, query, pl-sql, oracle12c

Estou tentando fazer a conversão de dados de um campo Long para Varchar, porem quando faço o procedimento, esta retornando o seguinte erro:

*ORA-01422: a extração exata retorna mais do que o número solicitado de linhas*

*ORA-06512: em line 4*

O codigo que estou utilizando é o seguinte:

`DECLARE
  VAR1 LONG;
  VAR2 VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
  SELECT DS_EVOLUCAO INTO VAR1 FROM PRE_MED WHERE HR_PRE_MED = '01/08/2019'; 
  VAR2 := SUBSTR(VAR1, 1, 32000);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VAR2);
END;`

Os campos talves possam exceder os 32000 de espaço do campo, por isso usei o SUBSTR, mas mesmo assim não consigo sucesso.

Comment: Um SELECT em PLSQL deve retornar uma e somente uma linha, para mais de uma linha use um CURSOR, o erro nada tem com o TYPE ( que pode até ter também).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O select: `"SELECT DS_EVOLUCAO INTO VAR1 FROM PRE_MED WHERE HR_PRE_MED = '01/08/2019';"`

Deve estar retornado mais de um resultado, tente usar:

```
"SELECT DS_EVOLUCAO INTO VAR1 FROM PRE_MED WHERE HR_PRE_MED = '01/08/2019' AND ROWNUM < 2;"
```

Ou aumentar o numero de filtros.

Para imprimir todas as linhas você pode fazer assim:

```
"DECLARE
  VAR2 VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
  FOR REG IN (SELECT DS_EVOLUCAO FROM PRE_MED WHERE HR_PRE_MED = '01/08/2019')
    LOOP
       VAR2 := SUBSTR(REG.DS_EVOLUCAO, 1, 32000);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VAR2);
    END LOOP;   
END;"
```

Comment: Porem eu preciso que traga todos os registros da data mesmo Bruno, é possível ?

Comment: Pode sim, já editei a resposta

Comment: Obrigado Bruno, agora se voce puder me ajudar, preciso inserir um LIKE '%SEPSE%' para trazer apenas os registros que tenham essa descrição no campo Long. Como consigo?

Comment: Não dá para fazer isso direto da coluna long ou você faz um if usando o varchar2 ou transforma o long em clob, mas neste ultimo caso vai depender da versão do oracle que esta usando.

Comment: Estou na versão 12c, porem acho q alterar o campo não sera viavel sem autorização do fornecedor do sistema... poderia me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso usando if com varchar2?

Answer (score 0):

Basta criar essa função, passando como parametro a tabela, o campo e o ROWID do registro. A Funcao já converte o LONG para varchar2 limitando em 4000 caractéres.

```
create or replace function fn_longtovarchar(
       v_table varchar2, 
       v_campo varchar2,
       v_rowid varchar2
) return varchar2 is
    t_sql varchar2(4000);
    t_varlong LONG;
    t_vartxt VARCHAR2(4000);
begin

  t_sql := 'select '||v_campo||' from '||v_table||' where rowid = '''||v_rowid||'''';
  
  execute immediate t_sql into t_varlong;
  
  t_vartxt := substr(t_varlong, 1, 4000);
  
  return(t_vartxt);

end;
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).